# excel use if statement results in countif function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have created a table "tblVehicleDailyUse" which (among other things) lists a Date, Vehicle ID and Driver's Name.  Using the data in this table I am attempting to fill a matrix beginning in cell B4 listing each vehicle and the driver that has driven the subject vehicle the most in the last 30 days.  The equation below goes into cell D4.

I attempted to use the following equation, but this just returns #VALUE! in each row of the Array.  I have also tried using a static Driver Name -- all to no avail.

> =MAX(COUNTIF(IF((tblVehicleDailyUse[[#Data],[CCH VID]]=$B4)*(tblVehicleDailyUse[[#Data],[Date]]<=TODAY())*(tblVehicleDailyUse[[#Data],[Date]]>=TODAY()-30), tblVehicleDailyUse[[#Data],[Driver]],0), tblVehicleDailyUse[[#Data],[Driver]]))

What have I done wrong or is this even possible?  Thanks.

Example data:

| DATE | VID | DRIVER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/10/2022 | A001 | John Doe |
| 01/10/2022 | B015 | Sam Slade |
| 01/10/2022 | C003 | Jane Doe |
| 01/10/2022 | ABC001 | Tom Smith |
| 01/11/2022 | A001 | John Doe |
| 01/11/2022 | A012 | Sam Slade |
| 01/11/2022 | B015 | Jane Doe |
| 01/11/2022 | ABC001 | Tom Smith |
| 01/12/2022 | C003 | Jane Doe |
| 01/12/2022 | A001 | Jane Doe |
| 01/12/2022 | C003 | Sam Slade |

Comment: Do you have the source table?

Comment: Basically the table is a Date Variable, followed by two Text Variables per row (record) it is in this format:  [date], [vehicle ID], [driver name].

Comment: Could you edit your question with some sample data.  We're notoriously lazy at figuring out what your data looks like. Many people would probably have skipped this question for that reason.  You can format your data using a markdown table generator:  https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Answer (score 0):

OK.  So resolved this a different way.

Created a field in the Driver Table, "CountByVehicle".  This field contains the formula:

> =SUM(IF((tblVehicleDailyUse[[#Data],[CCH VID]]=$B$4)*(tblVehicleDailyUse[[#Data],[Driver]]=[@[DRIVER
> LIST]]),1,0))

This sums the number of times each driver appears in the tblVehicleDailyUse Table for the Vehicle in question, still stored in $B$4.  Then I can use the formula:

> =INDEX(tblDriverList[[#All],[DRIVER_LIST]],MATCH(MAX(tblDriverList[[#All],[CountByVeh]]),tblDriverList[[#All],[CountByVeh]],0))

This returns the (first) Driver Name in the list with the most entries in tblVehicleDailyUse for the Vehicle in question.  A little clunky, but acceptable for my purposes.

Currently this resolves my issue. But this only looks at one vehicle at a time; problematic if I should need a more global solution.